# Cassandra Count Aggregate over intervals

Tags: cassandra

I have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE table (
id text,
time_stamp timestamp,
value text,
PRIMARY KEY (id, time_stamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time_stamp DESC)
```

What I want is to obtain the counts in intervals of any arbitrary time unit. Example:

```
{ "start": "03-08-2016 00:00:00.000", "end": "03-08-2016 12:00:00.000",  
  "interval": 1, "unit":"HOURS"}
```

This would be the input to return a list of counts in a 12 hour interval, counting every 1 hour. The result I want is like [12, 2, 44, ..., 212].

I know I can do multiple

```
select count(*) from table where time_stamp > '03-08-2016 00:00:00.000' and time_stamp < '03-08-2016 01:00:00.000' allow filtering;
select count(*) from table where time_stamp > '03-08-2016 01:00:00.000' and time_stamp < '03-08-2016 02:00:00.000' allow filtering;
```

But that would be multiple queries. Is there any way to do this faster?

Comment: There isn't really anything that can be done "faster" when you're using `ALLOW FILTERING`.  You should probably be partitioning on day (ex: 20160308) instead of id.  Then you wouldn't need `ALLOW FILTERING` at all.

Comment: Do you think something like kairosdb would be better to use? The only aggregation feature I need is count but kairosdb is able to do it in sampling intervals like I need.

Comment: In that case, KairosDB is probably what you want.  Cassandra can't do what you want here, and it also isn't going to perform well with your current data model.

Comment: The thing is, kairosdb uses Cassandra as a datastore. Wouldn't it just be doing what I would be doing? I can change the data model if needed

Answer (score 0):

For custom count by intervals, you can create an User Defined Aggregate (UDA). Read my blob posts to avoid the caveats:

UDF deep dive: http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=1876
UDF/UDA best practices & caveats: http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2015